# D3D11 LoadLibrary fails even when DLL is present and other DX11 apps work

Tags: remote-debugging, direct3d, vmware-workstation

I have a VMWare10 VM of Win7x64 Ult, and have confirmed that DX11 is installed per the DXDIAG control panel.

I have also confirmed that D3D11.dll is in System32.

When the app attempts to LoadLibrary('D3D11.dll'...), however, it fails.  I get back 87, which is merely invalid parameter.  This is within the DXUT framework, not my own code, so I'm fairly confident it's an environment issue and not a bug.

I'm trying to remotely debug it on this fresh Win7 VM that has nothing else except the remote debugger tools installed (and whatever updates it silently took overnight possibly).

VMWare is set to enable 3D acceleration (and the checkbox is on but greyed, so I cannot change it).

When not debugging, it bails at the same place right after LoadLibrary, as does the release version of the build.

I should add that I can get the older NVidia DX11 samples to run, so besides the DLL being installed, clearly someone is able to use it.

I've tried release and debug builds to make sure it's not looking for the debug components.  I just can't imagine why LoadLibrary would fail on a DLL that's clearly present.  I ran Depends.exe on D3d11.dll and only a couple of delay-load entry points are missing, and all static imports are there, which shouldn't cause the thing not to load.

Comment: I should add that I can get the older NVidia DX11 samples to run, so besides the DLL being installed, clearly someone is able to use it.

Comment: Are you building an x86 binary?  If so, is `d3d11.dll` also present in `\windows\syswow64`? Also, make sure you're passing the right kind of string depending on whether you're using unicode.  If you're not sure, try replacing it with `LoadLibraryA("d3d11.dll")`.